# Apply jquery to page that loaded to a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a div that load an external page.

**index.php**

```
<div class="loadWow"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".loadWow").load("external.php");
    });

    $(".newLink").click(function(){
       var link = $(this).attr('rev');
       $(".loadWow").load(link);
    });

</script>
```

**external.php**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="newLink" rev="other.php">Load Another Page</a>
```

As you can see, **loadWow** DIV will load **external.php**. 
My question is, how can i change the loaded page on the **loadWow** by clicking the link from an external page (**external.php**).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: like this ? $(".newLink").attr("href", "changed.php");

Comment: plz put some more explanation here what you want exactly???

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I already got the answer down there. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, what you want is when you have loaded your new page (external.php) you can click on link on this new page and then reload the div. If I guess right, you need to use this code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.newLink', function(){
       var link = $(this).attr('rev');
       $(".loadWow").load(link);
}
```

If you give directly the newLink class as reference, jQuery won't find your class because it's not loaded in the DOM.

Comment: It works!! Thank you very much for your explanation, i find it difficult to find the right keyword while googling.
Thank you very much sir. :D